# JavaScript and Browserify Function

Tags: javascript

I'am using browserify for short time. Installation and bundle.js creation are ok.
My concern is about the factory.js file (which cause problem). This file should instantiate all requested class.

When I execute the program, i'am getting the following error:

**createViewHandler is not a function**

Here is an extract of my code:

Router.js file

```
const factory = require('../factory/factory.js');
class Router {

  /**URL a atteindre */
  #url;
  #viewHandler

  constructor(url){

     this.url = url;
     this.#viewHandler= factory.createViewHandler('/'); //probleme here ->createViewHandler is not a function
  }      
}
module.exports = Router
```

viewHandler.js file

```
class ViewHandler{

#url

  constructor(url){

    this.url = url;
  }
  

}
module.exports = ViewHandler
```

factory.js file

```
const Router = require('../router/router.js');
const ViewHandler = require('../htmlElementHandler/createPage/viewHandler.js');

const factory = {

  createViewHandler : (url)=>{
     return new ViewHandler(url);
  },

 createRouter : (url)=>{
    return new Router(url);
 }
}
module.exports = factory
```

Comment: Why does Router.js import Factory.js and Factory.js import Router.js? Seems like a cyclic nightmare

Comment: router instantiate viewHandler tough factory.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem is solved.
I need to split my factory.js file per class to instantiate.

Here is my new structure:

viewHandlerFactory.js file

```
 const ViewHandler = require('../htmlElementHandler/createPage/viewHandler.js');

 const  viewHandlerFactory = {

 createViewHandler : (url)=>{
    
    return new ViewHandler(url);
 }
};

module.exports = viewHandlerFactory;
```

routerFactory.js file

```
const Router = require('../router/router.js');

  const routerFactory = {

  createRouter : (url)=>{
    
    return new Router(url);
  }
};

module.exports =  routerFactory;
```